# How can I get the width or height of an image field image on Octobercms

Tags: image, twig, octobercms, twig-filter

I try this method to get image dimensions:

```
{% set image_width = fields.sec_port_image.width %}
{% set image_height = fields.sec_port_image.height %}

<a href="{{ fields.sec_port_image|media }}" width="{{ image_width }}" height="{{ image_height }}">
```

but without success. I Also tried:

```
{% set image_width = fields.sec_port_image.width|media %}
```

and

```
{% set image_width = fields.sec_port_image|media.width %}
```

but also without success.

Is there a way on Octobercms to get image dimensions using twig?

Comment: What kind of object is `sec_port_image`? Does it have the public properties `width` and `height` or the public getter `getWidth()` or `getHeight()`?

Comment: sec_port_image is a Octobercms mediafinder widget field (https://octobercms.com/docs/api/backend/formwidgets/mediafinder).

Comment: As seen in the source the properties are called `imageWidth` and `imageHeight`

Comment: Yes, i also try {% set image_width = fields.sec_port_image.imageWidth %} without success. imageWidth points to image preview on Octobercms backend and not to original image uploaded.

Comment: Ah you should mention you are looking for the original measurements. I'd suggest adding a `Twig_Filter` or something that does this for you then as you can't retrieve the originals one straight from that object

Answer (score 0):

Extend `twig` in order to get the original size of your image. Something like this should work (not tested but you'll get the idea)

First create a registration class, see here for a [reference](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration#extending-twig).

```
<?php
    class Registration {
        public function registerMarkupTags()
        {
            return [
                'filters' => [
                    // A global function, i.e str_plural()
                    'image_width' => [$this, 'getImageWidth'],
                    'image_height' => [$this, 'getImageHeight'],
                ],
            ];
        }

        private $images = [];

        public function getImageWidth($url) {
            return $this->getImageSize($url) ? $this->getImageSize($url)['width'] : null;
        }

        public function getImageHeight($url) {
            return $this->getImageSize($url) ? $this->getImageSize($url)['height'] : null;
        }

        private function getImageSize($url) {
            if (!isset($this->images[$url])) {
                $data = @getimagesize($url);
                if ($data) {
                    $this->images[$url] = [
                        'width'     => $data[0],
                        'height'    => $data[1],
                    ];
                }else{
                    $this->images[$url] = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->images[$url];
    }
```

If done correctly you then could use the new filters inside your template like this

```
{% set source = fields.sec_port_image|media %}
<a href="{{ source }}" width="{{ source|image_width }}" height="{{ source|image_height }}">
```